# Is there a non-trivial example in which int* x = new int is practically useful?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and I am faced with two new cases:

- `int * x = new int`  to dynamically create an object `x`. (`int` can be replaced by other types for sure).
- `int *y = new int[<other variable>]` to dynamically create an array object `y`.

It is understandable that the second case is very useful to create an array that we don't know its size at compile time.

## Question

Is there any practically useful example for which the first case is really needed? What is wrong with my understanding here?

Comment: Neither should be seen anymore. If you need the first case you should use `auto x = std::make_unique<int>();` instead (or maybe `std::make_shared<int>();` in certain cases). If you need the second you should default to `std::vector<int> y(<other variable>);` instead.

Comment: Yes there are such examples, e.g. in various theories for implementing counters for smartpointers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In practice, standard smart pointer control blocks are more complicated than a single `int`. They need to be synchronized and they generally use at least two counters, one for `shared_ptr` instances and one for `weak_ptr` instances. And they also may contain a deleter. Edit : Though maybe someone's figured out some way of cramming all of that in an `int`, but I've never heard of something like that before.

Comment: For things larger than `int`s (classes/structs) you might need to store the pointer in some container, or you might prefer to pass a pointer around rather than copying an entire object (though, passing using references might be better)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Though IIRC I have seen discussed such stuff with Alexej Andrescou's discussions about variants how to implement shared pointers and allocate counters dynamically, and what policy based design should be taken for certain use cases.

Comment: @PhilM: Could you describe it with a simple code?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have no doubt counters can be allocated dynamically, but I doubt they are just `int`s. Note that I'm not arguing that owning raw pointers and dynamic allocation don't have a place in low level container implementation. My original comment is meant to provide a general rule of thumb for typical use cases.

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy _"Could you describe it with a simple code?"_ Such examples would unlikely appear with _simple code_. They would be more tangling _esoteric spheres_ of c++ implementations.

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy Cases where dynamic allocation of single elements like that don't come up with simple demonstrative examples. They emerge from the complexity of more practical and larger projects. It's difficult to design a short example that illustrates a case where you *need* to dynamically allocate a single `int`. Edit : Would this comment actually be an answer to the question? There *might* be a clever short example I can't think of.

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy `int * x = new int` -- Sure, I've seen this, but only in those horrible C++ courses and assignments that say "you must use pointers".

Comment: `while(true) new int;` to see what happens upon memory exhaustion. Or to see how inefficient and inadequate to c++ are the default memory allocation algorithm provided by default by the system, like the 35 years old glibc malloc?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux "_They need to be synchronized_" 1) Not all ref counted (RC) smart ptr do (or should) support weak ref. 2) Not all RC tool are designed for MT, not all programs should bear that burden if it isn't needed (and even if threads are used, it's OK to use plain `int` operations for RC as long as the RC is thread private). 3) You can get proper thread synchronisation on top of `int` with the correct primitives.

Comment: @curiousguy I did specifically mention I was talking about standard smart pointers.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I misread "standard smart pointer". I thought you meant "industrial strength" (industry standard) not `std::`, sorry about that! (And yes I'm really tired right now :(

Answer (score 2):

Imagine some task that's going to be completed asynchronously and that is going to produce an integer result. You need to be able to give the asynchronous task logic a pointer to the integer in which the result will be stored and you need to ensure that integer lives at the same location in memory for the duration of the asynchronous task.

You need to dynamically-allocate some structure that will contain that long-lived integer. And if that integer is really all that you need, it might make sense to just allocate that integer itself dynamically.

However, realistically, there are a few problems:

1. It would probably make more sense to use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` for this to make the management of the lifetime more sane.
2. In almost every realistic case, you'll need more than just that single integer. For example, you probably need some way to synchronize safe access to that integer or some handle to the execution of the task.

Comment: For the first task, a [`std::promise`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise)/[`std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) pair is designed to solve that problem. Though internally it likely dynamically allocates an object of the result's type as you describe.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably very few cases where dynamic allocation of a single `int` object would be practically useful.

Furthermore, there are probably very few cases where storing the result of `new` or `new[]` in a bare pointer would be practically useful.

Now, if we were to generalise the question into *"is there a practical use case for allocating a single object dynamically"* and we were to allocate a class type, and we were to store the result in a smart pointer, for example this could be practically useful:

```
// member declaration
std::unique_ptr<Big> ptr_member;

// in the member initialisation list:
ptr_member(std::make_unique<Big>(args...))
```

This can make specifically in the case where the size of `Big` is, as the name implies, big. Dynamic allocation may be necessary in such case because the space reserved for automatic storage is typically limited. Furthermore, this makes moving and swapping of the object much faster.